# Adjust the position of path label

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

My problem is the path label mixes the arrow, my code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', auto, semithick, node distance=3cm]
\node[state]    (x0)                     {$x_0$};
\node[state]    (x3)[above right of=x0]   {$x_3$};
\node[state]    (x4)[below right of=x0]   {$x_4$};
\node[state]    (x1)[right of=x3]   {$x_1$};
\node[state]    (x6)[right of=x4]   {$x_6$};
\node[state]    (x2)[below right of=x1]   {$x_2$};
\node[state]    (x5)[below right of=x2]   {$x_5$};
\path
(x1) edge[loop above]     node{$1/2$}         (x1)
   edge[ left]     node{$1/2$}     (x3)
(x0) edge[loop left]     node{$1/3$}         (x0)
   edge[bend left]     node{$1/3$}     (x3)
   edge[bend left]     node{$1/3$}     (x4)
(x3) edge[loop above]     node{$1/2$}         (x3)
   edge[bend left]     node{$1/2$}     (x0)
(x2) edge[loop right]     node{$1$}         (x2)
(x5) edge[loop left]     node{$1$}         (x5)
(x4) edge[bend left]     node{$1/2$}     (x0)
   edge[bend right]     node{$1/2$}     (x3)
(x6) edge[ left]     node{$1/3$}     (x1)      
   edge[ left]     node{$1/3$}     (x2)
   edge[ right]     node{$1/3$}     (x4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So my question is how to move, for example the label of path x3-x1 above the line? And move the label of path x3-x4 right of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are positioned "wrong" because you stated them "wrong". Thus you could change the positioning keys of the corresponding `node`s as in [revision 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/425418/1) of my answer (see the comments in the code there).

But since you use the `auto` key, most nodes are positioned right by default. And if you thing they should be "on the other side" simply add the `swap` key.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        arrows,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,
    >=stealth',
    auto,
    semithick,
    node distance=3cm,
    state/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
    },
]
    \begin{scope}[
        every node/.append style={
            state,
        },
    ]
        \node (x0)                     {$x_0$};
        \node (x3) [above right of=x0] {$x_3$};
        \node (x4) [below right of=x0] {$x_4$};
        \node (x1) [right of=x3]       {$x_1$};
        \node (x6) [right of=x4]       {$x_6$};
        \node (x2) [below right of=x1] {$x_2$};
        \node (x5) [below right of=x2] {$x_5$};
    \end{scope}

    \path
    (x1) edge [loop above] node        {$1/2$}  (x1)
         edge              node [swap] {$1/2$}  (x3)
    (x0) edge [loop left]  node        {$1/3$}  (x0)
         edge [bend left]  node        {$1/3$}  (x3)
         edge [bend left]  node        {$1/3$}  (x4)
    (x3) edge [loop above] node        {$1/2$}  (x3)
         edge [bend left]  node        {$1/2$}  (x0)
    (x2) edge [loop right] node        {$1$}    (x2)
    (x5) edge [loop left]  node        {$1$}    (x5)
    (x4) edge [bend left]  node        {$1/2$}  (x0)
         edge [bend right] node        {$1/2$}  (x3)
    (x6) edge              node        {$1/3$}  (x1)
         edge              node        {$1/3$}  (x2)
         edge              node [swap] {$1/3$}  (x4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]